# Sum values based on first occurrence of other column using excel formula with Subtotal function

Tags: excel-formula

I already viewed the posting about summing values based on first occurrence in another cell but I would like to add a complication and nestle in a subtotal function. Basically I would like to sum values in the Score column based upon the first and only instance of a value in Color with subtotal filtering via one formula.

There are two formulas that somewhat give me the two components required but I'm limited in my formulaic abilities to combine these:

Sum values based on first occurrence in another column:

`=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B8/COUNTIF(A2:A8,A2:A8))`

Subtotal with sumproduct:

`=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B8,SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(C2:C8,ROW(C2:C8)-MIN(ROW(C2:C8)),0,1)))`

**Unfiltered Table**

[image: Unfiltered Table]

**Filtered Table**

[image: Filtered Table]

Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: can you share the link (edit the question) of the " the posting about summing values based on first occurrence in another cell" ? (just to get a clearer picture of the formula/case..

Answer (score 0):

You can combine both formulas as below:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B8/COUNTIF(A2:A8,A2:A8),SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(A2:A8,ROW(A2:A8)-MIN(ROW(A2:A8)),0,1)))
```

The first part of the above formula is from your `SUMPRODUCT` formula so it is easy to understand, the second part of the formula should be using `3 - COUNT` for the `SUBTOTAL` formula so it will return `1` for values showing in the filtered range and `0` for values that are not.

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)